# Problemas após alterar localização da pasta VENDOR no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Tenho um Aplicativo em Laravel 8. Inicialmente com instalação padrão, porém, por questões de organização precisei alterar a pasta vendor do projeto para '../../vendor'.

Agora, ao rodar qualquer comando tanto pelo composer quando pelo artisan recebo algo parecido com isso:

```
C:\1.PHP\teste\dashboard> php artisan --version

In Auth.php line 60:
                                                                                     
In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.
```

Já rodei `composer update`, `composer require laravel/ui` seguido por `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` e sem sucesso.

Também em uma ultima tentativa desesperada, tentei subir o projeto para um repositorio git, clonar e refazer deploy com `composer install` mas o problema permanece.

aqui está meu composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^3.6",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.40",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
        "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^8.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
            "Modules\\": "Modules/"

        },
        "files": ["padrao/globais.php","padrao/globalProjeto.php"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir":"../../vendor",
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: tentou deletar a pastar vendor e rodar o comando "composer install"? Outra coisa, eu não trocaria a pasta vendor de local (minha opnião), pois o Laravel tem suas estruturas, e não sei qual teu nível de conhecimento, mas mexer com coisas mais sensíveis sem o devido conhecimento não é bom, pode acarretar em problemas como este.

Comment: @DanielKartabilBernardi Ja tentei excluir e reinstalar usando `composer install` mas continuo com o mesmo retorno: 

`Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In Auth.php line 60:

  In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1`

Answer (score -3):

Colega, como vai?

É necessário recriar o cache das páginas. Execute os comandos abaixo **na ordem em que vos escrevo**.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```